# Integrated Windows authentication in Microsoft Edge

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, windows-authentication

I am trying to implement Integrated Windows authentication on Edge, but it always prompts me for credentials, whereas Integrated Windows authentication is working for IE, Chrome and Firefox. I have tried adding the site to local intranet sites in security options and enabled automatic login but no luck on edge browser.

Does Edge support Integrated Windows authentication?

I have tried adding the site to local intranet sites in security options and enabled automatic login as well login with current username and password.

Answer (score 6):

Which version of Microsoft Edge version are you using?
Please check the following configuration to Enable Integrated Windows Authentication:

1. Open Internet Explorer and select "**Tools**" dropdown.
2. Select the "**Advanced**" tab.
3. Scroll down to the "**Security**" section until you see "**Enable Integrated Windows Authentication**". Select the box next to this field to enable.
4. Select the "**Security**" tab.
5. Select "**Local Intranet**" and select the "**Custom Level**" or "**Advanced**" button.
6. Scroll down to "**User Authentication**" > "**Logon**".
7. Checked the "**Automatic logon with current user name and password**" option.
8. In the "**Security**" tab, select "**Local Intranet**" option and click the "**Sites**" button.
9. Click the "**Advanced**" button, then, add your website to the zone.
10. Close the window and apply the configuration.

If still not working, I suggest you could feedback your issue to [Microsoft Edge platform forum](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/), like [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/how-do-i-enable-integrated-windows-authentication/5668886b-659f-4fec-97b5-db68593235b9).

Comment: I found that SSO does not work in incognito (InPrivate) mode on either Edge or Firefox. Make sure to use a regular tab when testing Windows authentication.

Answer (score 5):

It may be because of [AuthServerAllowlist](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#authserverallowlist). You can check your policies at `edge://policy/`.

> Specifies which servers to enable for integrated authentication.
> Integrated authentication is only enabled when Microsoft Edge receives
> an authentication challenge from a proxy or from a server in this
> list.
>
> [...]
>
> If you don't configure this policy, Microsoft Edge tries to detect if
> a server is on the intranet - only then will it respond to IWA
> requests. If the server is on the internet, IWA requests from it are
> ignored by Microsoft Edge.

As the documentation states; if your server/site isn't included in the AuthServerAllowlist and Edge can't identify your site as an intranet site Edge won't use Integrated Windows Authentication.

Comment: Good answer, but note that the reg key is actually AuthServerAllowlist (without the ED on AllowED).

Comment: @Kidquick Good catch. I've changed the text.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Integrated Windows Authentication

Use the following procedure to enable silent authentication on each computer.

1. Open the Windows Settings and search Internet Options.

   The following window opens.

[image]

2. Click Local intranet > Sites.
3. Click Advanced.

[image]

4. Enter the tenant specific URL into the Websites text box.

[image]

5. Click Close.

Comment: It seems 9i cannot find official page0 Edge Chromium follow the same setting.

Comment: This is not enough, this answer worked for me: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034199/integrated-windows-authentication-in-microsoft-edge#answer-57036326)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell and from what I have read, Edge does not support Integrated Windows authentication; at least as of version 42.17134.1098.0.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, for time being I am using this option to login without prompting credentials. Edge Settings -> "Reload in internet explorer mode". Hope this helps someone.
[Edge Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoxDe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution, it works like a charm:
copy and paste this into a reg file and import into your registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"WindowsHelloForHTTPAuthEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452099/5030206