# Windows Security dialog in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-security

I am using the latest version of Microsoft Edge (Version 81.0.416.68 (Official Build) (64-bit)). When I'm trying to login a specific site, not for all sites, it's popping up the "Windows Security" dialog followed "Sign in to access this site" asking username and password. Using Chrom I just get the 'Sign in' dialog asking username and password.

So my question is, why does Microsoft Edge have the "Windows Security" dialog, it is quite annoying even it does not prefill any saved username and password, like another dialog box?

How can I disable this, get a normal "Sign in" dialog with a prefill saved username and password or I need to do some settings for prefill saved username and password in the "Windows Security" dialog?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Found an even easier method instead of the whole Import Policies mess.

Navigate to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]`

Create a new DWORD value named `"WindowsHelloForHTTPAuthEnabled"` with value 0

Or copy and paste this into a reg file and import into your registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"WindowsHelloForHTTPAuthEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Original method I found using Group Policies:

1. Go to Microsoft Edge for Business site at [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download)
2. Get policy files [image: polity files]
3. Open the downloaded file MicrosoftEdgePolicyTemplates.zip
4. Open folder windows\admx from the zip [image: admx files]
5. Copy these files into C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions [image: admx files]
6. Open Group Policy Editor: run gpedit.msc
7. Go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Microsoft Edge > HTTP Authentication > Windows Hello for HTTP Auth Enabled
8. Set it to disabled [image]
9. Done! Edge will now show the basic Chromium login dialog[image: chromium login dialog]

You could choose Computer Configuration policy instead of User Configuration to apply this change to all users.

Answer (score 0):

You could open Internet Options and check the User Authentication option:

1. Type "Internet Options" in the search box next to the Start menu button.
2. Open **Internet Options** and click on **Security** tab.
3. If the site is in Internet zone, click on **Internet** and under Security level click on **Custon level**.
4. Scroll down for **User Authentication** and check if you have checked **Prompt for user name and password**.
5. Choose other options if you have checked **Prompt for user name and password**.
6. Click **OK, Apply** then restart the browser to try again.

Comment: Are you the author of the website? If you're, you could provide the minimal, reproducible code so that we can test and see how to help. If not, could you please provide the website link so that we can also have a test? Besides, the pop up might be a scam. You could refer to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/all/edge-windows-security-keeps-asking-for-username/148e7b1f-30f0-4179-ae49-b7bb762bacac).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide, it's my office portal.

Comment: It's hard to debug without any information about the website. You could try to check if it is a scam and scan your PC for malware and check the Credential Manager.