# Prompting of credentials on Edge browser despite already logged in on client PCs

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, windows-server-2016, rsa-archer-grc, cots

Some background:

We were accessing our RSA Archer application on IE 11 via SSO, and all has been well. But we are required to move on to Edge browser, and that's where we started having the Windows Security credential prompt coming out, whenever we tried to access the application on Edge browser.

The strange thing is, the application is able to load up on Edge properly, in the logged in state, and then the prompt will appear. We can just click on Cancel to close the prompt and we are able to use the application normally. All end users on their client PCs encountered the same problem.

We want to remove the credentials prompt. The RSA support team has confirmed it is not an issue of their product, since there's no problem over at IE. What we have done on our end on the servers:

- Enabled SSL on our load balanced environment
- Updated the web.config file of the application with the entry below:

> ```
>  <security mode="Transport">
>  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
>  </security>
> ```

- Configure IIS settings to allow Anonymous Authentication instead of Windows Authentication for the application pages.

Will greatly appreciate some assistance or suggestions on how to move forward. Thanks!

---

Addon after investigation:

After finally being able to investigate via the development tool for this, we discovered that apparently, the behavior of some components / javascripts were different on IE / Edge.

On IE, if the components / javascripts took too long to load, it will fail (status 304) and retry again until it succeeded (status 200).

On Edge, instead of failing, it will go into "Pending", and then the credentials prompts pops out, and usually there's more than one prompt. We suspect the number is based on the number of pending components / javascripts that are in "Pending". Clicking on Cancel on the prompt will caused the components to not load (status 304), and no retry will happen like in the case of IE.

Able to advise what's wrong? Is there a timeout in the Edge settings?

Comment: Have you tried in other browsers like Chrome to see if the issue persists? You can also navigate to `edge://policy/` to check if there's any policy which might be related with this issue in Edge. Besides, you can try the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034199/integrated-windows-authentication-in-microsoft-edge/57036326#57036326) to see if it can fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open Edges developer tools and go to the Network tab and see which request (URL) is prompting you for credentials.  Then you can see what IIS has configured for its security.