# How to get the authenticated username from the Browser?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, browser, kerberos, windows-authentication

I implemented a Windows Authentication using SPNEGO Filter. Everything works fine, in my request.getUserPrincipal() method I'm always getting the name of the user account it is running under, let's say testUser1. When I run the broswer as different user the browser should take the username of the new user lets say testUser2. But it doesn't happens like that, it takes the testUser1, the user with I'm logged in into my Windows account. My question is, how it would be possible to get the new username from the browser and then passing it to SPNEGO?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>login</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="login.css" library="css" />

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <div class="form">
        <h:form>
            <div id="inputText" class="inputTextVis">
                <h3>LDAP and Windows Authentication</h3>
                <h:outputText value="Username" />
                <h:inputText id="username" value="#{login.user}"></h:inputText>
                <h:message for="username"></h:message>
                <br /> <br />

                <h:outputText value="Password" />
                <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{login.pwd}"></h:inputSecret>
                <h:message for="password"></h:message>
                <br /> <br />
            </div>



            <h:commandButton action="#{login.authenticationCredentialsWindows}" value="Login"></h:commandButton>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="drop" value="#{login.authentication}"
                onchange="test(this.value)">
                <f:selectItem id="dropDownValue" itemValue="Active Directory"
                    itemLabel="Active Directory" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="Windows" itemLabel="Windows" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:outputScript name="login.js" library="javascript" />

        </h:form>


    </div>


</h:body>
</html>
```

```
public String authenticationCredentialsWindows() throws LoginException, ValidationException
    {
        

            try {

                HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                        .getExternalContext().getRequest();
                
                user = req.getRemoteUser();
                    
                ActiveDirectoryAuthentication activeDirectoryAuthentication = new ActiveDirectoryAuthentication();
                boolean auth;
                auth = activeDirectoryAuthentication.authenticateWithSpnego(req);
                if(auth) {
                    HttpSession session = SessionUtils.getSession();
                    session.setAttribute("username", user);
                    return "admin";
                }

            } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, e.getMessage(), e.getMessage()));

                // error: authentication failed
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());

                return "login";
            }
        }
        return "login";

    }
```

```
public boolean authenticateWithSpnego(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException, LoginException, ValidationException {
        
        Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (userPrincipal != null) {
            // User is authenticated
            String username = userPrincipal.getName();

            return true;
          
        } else {
            // User is not authenticated          
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which browser do you use for testing? Can you disable `Integrated Authentication` so it will prompt for credentials? Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036326/1505146) for example. I'm guessing that integrated authentication always uses the current user's Kerberos ticket.

Comment: @Tasos P. Thank you for answering my question! I will try to disable the Integrated Authentication, but it will take time due to security issues. It is possible to get the user name , wihout prompting the user?